# Using RPi.GPIO in Django app

Tags: rpi.gpio, web-server

How can RPi.GPIO be used in a Django app without running the app with root privileges i.e.

`sudo python manage.py runserver`

Comment: You could make a custom service to interface between the GPIO and the app.

Answer (score 2):

Currently RPi.GPIO has to be run with root priviliges to allow GPIOs access.

There are changes in the [pipeline](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/115/) which will remove that need, but those changes might be several weeks away.

Comment: is there a similar library which does not require root privileges?

Comment: @JayKarimi That depends on what you mean by similar.  My [pigpio Python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) module does not require that Python be run as root.  It works differently, it communicates GPIO requests to a separate daemon which does run as root.